# nlog archive all log files at end of each week

Tags: nlog

Requirements:

1. Roll each run
2. At the end of the week, archive all files

I want the current week's logs in the "d:\log\service" directory as plain text files. Then at the end of the week (sunday), zip and archive last weeks to the archive directory. I have tried ArchiveEvery="Sunday" but it only archives the Saturday log file.

```
<target name="rollingFile" layout="${layout}" xsi:type="File" encoding="UTF-8"
 createDirs="true" fileName="D:\Log\Service\Service-${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.log"
archiveFileName="D:\Log\Service\archives\Service-${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.zip" 
archiveOldFileOnStartup="true" archiveEvery="Day" 
archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence" archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"            
enableArchiveFileCompression="true" maxArchiveFiles="20" />
```

Comment: Why not use maxArchiveFiles="7" ?

Comment: Archive only archives the current file.  If you archive every day, then those have technically be archived.  Archive on Sunday assumes you only archive Sunday and the current log file has a weeks worth of logs entries. I would set up a PowerShell script or something through Windows scheduled tasks to archive the archives\\* directory on Sunday and keep NLog archiving daily.